# readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

> I use MongoDB as database . when I try to insert data into database
> from post man by the help of insert API . I get internal error BSON
> Type error . Get Below type of error

```
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:690) ~[bson-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:722) ~[bson-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:450) ~[bson-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:223) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.captureExpressionDependencies(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:202) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.getBindingContext(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:121) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:122) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.existByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.nilmani.mychat.service.UserService.register(UserService.kt:22) ~[main/:na]
    at com.nilmani.mychat.controller.UserAuthController.createUser(UserAuthController.kt:43) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at com.nilmani.mychat.config.JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.kt:94) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

> UserService.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.service

import com.nilmani.mychat.model.Role
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.User
import com.nilmani.mychat.repository.UserRepository
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.util.*

@Service
class UserService {
    val log : Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService::class.java)
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
    fun register(user:User,role:Role):User{
        log.info("Register user {}",user.userName)
        if (userRepository.existsByUserName(user.userName) == true){
            log.warn("UserName already Exist", user.userName)
        }
        if(userRepository.existByEmail(user.email) == true){
            log.warn("This email already Registred",user.email)
        }
        user.active = true
        user.password = user.password
        user.role = user.role/**it auto automatically get the user type from role due to some conflict  set role provided by user*/
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }
    /**this function find the user by her name*/
    fun findByUserName(userName:String):Optional<User>{
        log.info("retrive user and username{}",userName)
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName)
    }
}
```

> UserAuthController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.controller

import com.nilmani.mychat.ezception.BadRequestException
import com.nilmani.mychat.ezception.EmailAlreadyExistException
import com.nilmani.mychat.ezception.UserNameAlreadyExistException
import com.nilmani.mychat.payload.ApiResponse
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.Profile
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.Role
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.User
import com.nilmani.mychat.payload.Signup
import com.nilmani.mychat.service.UserService
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder
import java.net.URI


@RestController
class UserAuthController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userService: UserService

    val log:Logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAuthController::class.java)
    @PostMapping(value = ["/users"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun createUser(@ModelAttribute request:Signup):ResponseEntity<*>{
        log.info("create User",request.username)
        val user:User = User(
            userName = request.username,
            email = request.email,
            password = request.password,
            userProfile = Profile(
                displayName = request.name,
                profilePictureUrl = request.profilePicUrl,
            )
        )
        try {
            userService.register(user, Role.USER)
        }catch (e:UserNameAlreadyExistException){
            throw BadRequestException(e.message)
        }catch (e:EmailAlreadyExistException){
            throw BadRequestException(e.message)
        }
        val location : URI = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
            .fromCurrentContextPath().path("users/{username}")
            .buildAndExpand(user.userName).toUri()
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(location)
            .body(ApiResponse(true,"User Registered successfully"))
    }
}
```

> JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.config

import com.nilmani.mychat.model.InstaUserDetails
import com.nilmani.mychat.model.User
import com.nilmani.mychat.service.JwtTokenProvider
import com.nilmani.mychat.service.UserService
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import java.io.IOException
import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse


class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter : OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtConfig: JwtConfig
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userService: UserService

    constructor(
        jwtConfig: JwtConfig,
        jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider,
        userService: UserService
    ) {
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider
        this.userService = userService
    }

    /**
     * Same contract as for `doFilter`, but guaranteed to be
     * just invoked once per request within a single request thread.
     * See [.shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch] for details.
     *
     * Provides HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse arguments instead of the
     * default ServletRequest and ServletResponse ones.
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class,ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val header:String? = request.getHeader(jwtConfig.header)

        if (header != null) {
            if (!header.startsWith(jwtConfig.prefix)){
                filterChain.doFilter(request,response)
                return
            }
        }
        val token:String? = header?.replace(jwtConfig.prefix,"")
        if (jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)){
            val claims:Claims = jwtTokenProvider.getClaimsFromJWT(token)
            val username:String = claims.subject

            val auth:UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                userService.findByUserName(username)
                    .map{user:User ->
                        InstaUserDetails(
                            user.id,
                            user.userName,
                            user.password,
                            user.email,
                            user.createdAt,
                            user.updatedAt,
                            user.active,
                            user.userProfile,
                            user.role
                        )
                    }
                    .map { userDetails ->
                        val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities
                        )
                        authentication.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                        authentication
                    }
                    .orElse(null)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication=auth
        }else{
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
        }

       filterChain.doFilter(request,response)
    }

}
```

> I get The error in UserService class
> I don't know which type of issue it , this issue is first time for me
> and For First time I use MongoDB as a database
> User.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.model

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import java.time.LocalDate


@Document
open  class User(
    var id: String ="",
    var userName:String="",
    open var password:String="",
    var email:String="",
    var createdAt:LocalDate=LocalDate.now(),
    var updatedAt:LocalDate= LocalDate.now(),
    var active:Boolean=false,
    @NotNull
    var userProfile:Profile,
    @NotNull
    var role:Set<Role> = HashSet()
)
```

> Role.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.model

class Role(s: String) {
     val name: String? = ""

    companion object {
        val USER = Role("USER")
        val FACEBOOK_USER = Role("FACEBOOK_USER")
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is random but I got a similar error, trying to implement a custom codec for a java enum inside of a record. "writeEndDocument can only be called when State is NAME, not when State is VALUE" and for anyone who stumbles here I wanted to pass something on. I was mostly concerned with deserializing, with the decode method, which I thought was decoupled from encode. It turns out not implementing the encode method right will cause errors even if you only need to read from the db. Working with frameworks, it's sometimes all or nothing within a black box.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message in a completely different scenario: it was generated by `MongoItemReader` in a Spring-batch application because the provided JSON query was wrong.

It happened after having upgraded from Spring-boot 1.x to Spring-boot 2.x: in the new version the method `getQueryObject()` of spring-data-mongo's `Query` class returns a different type (as you can see comparing the [old Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html#getQueryObject--) with [the new one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.2.8/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html#getQueryObject--)) so its `toString()` is not a valid JSON query anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> In User entity class not provide the @Id which is belongs from
> "org.springframework.data.annotation.Id" when I use @Id in entity
> class error gone and work perfectly for me
> @Id handle all the mapping related task and automatically declare the
> id as a primary key